# Any hit for dereferencing std::tr1:shared_ptr vs. dereferencing a naked pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, smart-pointers, tr1

I realize that there is a (Sometimes significant) performance hit for creating, assigning, copying, and destroying a std::tr1::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr (due to the reference counting mechanisms).  Is it correct that once constructed, accessing the pointer wrapped by a shared_ptr has no performance penalty?

in other words: given

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<myClass> SharedA(new myClass);
myClass *NakedA = new myClass;
```

does

```
SharedA->someClassMember
```

have the same overhead as

```
NakedA->someClassMember
```

?

Comment: i dunno, what happens when you measure it?

Comment: What is the choice? Not using a shared_ptr even though it is needed?

Comment: @Doug T.- In simple test cases, it appears not to make a difference, however in a large code I am working on, my profiler is showing some overhead in accessing the pointer (though it appears it should be inlined, and thus make no difference)

Comment: @Bo- technically, a managed pointer is not "needed."  It tends to be a good design choice, and in most cases *should* be used.  In my case (a scientific research group code) I can afford the overhead of construction/assignement/etc, but accessing the shared_ptr is slowing things down too much, and from my understanding this should not be the case.

Comment: What kind of profiler are you using? A sampling profiler shouldn't be able to tell the difference if the `operator->` method has been inlined. An instrumenting profiler will log the call of the method no matter what, and the measurement will be skewed because it won't measure use of the plain old `->` operator on plain old pointers because it won't instrument those instructions at all.

Comment: @MarkD - If the code works with a naked pointer, why try something else? If it doesn't work, what are the options?

Comment: @sehe - Properly inlined, there *shouldn't* be an overhead.  My own, limited shared_ptr class has no overhead compared to a naked pointer when simply accessing the wrapped pointer and it appears to me (reading the std::tr1 and boost implementations) that they shouldn't have additional overhead either.  Was simply asking to see if I was missing something.

Comment: @Bo- because I am tired of fixing memory leaks as other people in the research group hack away at things.  As I mentioned in my response above, I am currently using my own cobbled together shared_ptr class, but would prefer to use something a bit more standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an optimized build without debugging support, there shouldn't be any overhead.  You can find out by taking a look at the implementation you are using.  Chances are, its `operator->` overload just returns the pointer to the pointed-to object and its `operator*` overload just dereferences this pointer.

(This is what the Visual C++ 2010 implementation of `std::shared_ptr` does:  each of those overloaded operators just calls a "get" function which just returns the pointer; there is no locking or other overhead of any kind.  Other implementations may be different.)

An unoptimized build may not inline the operator overload and if your implementation has extra debugging support that you enable, it may perform extra checks (e.g., perhaps an assert if you dereference a null pointer).

Comment: Thanks James- This is what I suspected, but didn't want to keep chasing my tail if I was not seeing clearly.

Answer (score 3):

All of the member functions of a smart pointer, including the dereference operator, can be inlined. Any good compiler *should* optimize away the abstraction.